# PowerApps - how duplicate records in gallery to display it as one?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-selected-items

[image]

For example, I only need to display 1IN_125AB to allow select 1.

The Gallery Name : `SalesItemGallery`

```
Items Field : Filter(IV00108,PRCLEVEL = SOGALLERY.Selected.PRCLEVEL)
```

**The right hand side form :**

Item Field= `SalesItemGallery.Selected`

Thing I had test, but having some error on selecting the records. For example, I put Gallery Items field as : `GroupBy(Filter(IV00108,PRCLEVEL = SOGALLERY.Selected.PRCLEVEL),"ITEMNMBR","DATA")`

It will be group and become 1, but I not sure how the form retrieve the value from gallery.

**Summary,**

1. I wish to know how exactly to removed duplicate item from gallery?
2. May I know how to search the value records?

Normally, I only write this method to search the records:

```
Search(IV00108,SearchOrder3.Text,"ITEMNMBR")
```

Comment: can't you use [distinct function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-distinct)